# Installing ASP.Net 3.5 in docker container

Tags: asp.net, docker, containers, windows-container

I'm trying to install ASP.Net 3.5 in my windows docker container using the below command

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All
```

I'm getting the below error

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 10.0.17763.1
>
> Image Version: 10.0.17763.615
>
> Enabling feature(s)
>   [==========================100.0%==========================]
>
> Error: 1058
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or
>   because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Also i tried different powershell commands like, but no luck. Getting same error

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET
```

Anyone faced this issue, Any workaround or solution?

Comment: .NET 30 source is not shipped with windows container image and hence you'd need to get installation mapped into container (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-net-framework-35-by-using-windows-powershell)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gregory Suvalian. In the above link says we need to install .net 3.5 from shared network path. Can this be a docker C drive? and what files needs to be copied under \sources\sxs? (Iss it dotNetFx35setup.exe or something else). I copied this file folder to c\sources folder of docker and using this command RUN dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:C:\Sources /LimitAccess but still im getting error "The source files could not be found."

Comment: You need full installation of Windows 2016/2019 to copy those files into container first and then install it

Comment: @Mathiyazhagan did you found a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 4):

Answered in https://superuser.com/questions/1498853/cannot-install-windows-feature-net-framework-features-in-docker-image

Example (using `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809`):

```
PS> Set-Service -Name wuauserv -StartupType Manual
PS> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature:NetFx3 /All

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1282

Image Version: 10.0.17763.1457

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```